# help with doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures

I have a class LinkedList clas that has a class called Node

```
class Node {
public:
Node() { next = NULL; prev = NULL; }
~Node() {}
public :
Node *next;
Node *prev;
T data;


 };
```

In the same LinkedList class i have the following function defininitions, because it is all in a header file

```
 public:
LinkedList();
~LinkedList();

// methods -- note that the return values are of type T. Don't return a Node!
  void append(T item);
  T get(int idx);
  void insert(int idx, T item);
  void map(T (*pf)(T item));
  T remove(int index);
  int size();
  void unshift(T item);
```

No I am trying to implement the operations

first i need to return a new, empty Linked List.

please help, i tried many things

would it be as simple as

```
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() {

head = NULL;
current = NULL;

}
```

Comment: We can't smell what the actual problem is you know...

Comment: Homework? Please add a tag. Also, a null Node pointer is an empty list. If you have at least one node, it's not empty anymore.

Comment: Has that home work smell.  What have you gotten to work.  Is there compile errors.  All of that info would be awesome.

Comment: im not asking you guys to do this for me, i just want some help

Comment: Help with **what**? I see no question marks in your post. [Click here](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be as simple as?

```
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() {
    head = NULL;
    current = NULL;
}
```

Yes.

Comment: this doesnt work with the current set up, do i have to add a private: Node *head, *current; in the linkedlist constructor